# I have a function in excel VBA which takes input from user using textbox

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007, inputbox

I have written a macro that takes input from user and returns a cell data.
Is there any way that triggers the process to run from macro 
That is the the inputbox opens up directly with one click without having to go to VBA and run it?

Comment: you can right click in almost any shape and link your macro to the click of that shape.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in Worksheet code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Call showMsg
End Sub
```

Put this in your module:

```
Sub showMsg()
Dim data As String
data = InputBox("Hello", "Title")
End Sub
```

You can use other worksheet or workbooks events as well e.g
(It will run macro whenever you open file)

```
  Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call showMsg
  End Sub
```

Comment: Side note: you don't need the `Call` to run a macro.